# What favor did Moody owe Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, defence-against-the-dark-arts, alastor-moody

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, “Professor Moody" mentioned that he would only be teaching for a year, and only because he owed Dumbledore a favor. What was this favor and what made it so important that it made Moody agree to give up a year of his life to teach DADA?

Here it is from *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*:

> "You'll be Arthur Weasley's son, eh?" Moody said. "Your father got me out of a very tight corner a few days ago.... Yeah, I'm staying just the one year. Special favor to Dumbledore.... One year, and then back to my quiet retirement."
>
> <sup>~ *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*</sup>

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I don't think there is necessarily an indication that Moody owed Dumbledore a favor. Here is the relevant quote from Chapter Fourteen:

> "You'll be Arthur Weasley's son, eh?" Moody said. "Your father got me out of a very tight corner a few days ago.... Yeah, I'm staying just the one year. Special favor to Dumbledore.... One year, and then back to my quiet retirement."

All this says is that Moody agreed to teach for one year as a favor to Dumbledore. It doesn't say  that he *owed* a favor to Dumbledore. People do favors for others all the time, especially when they like and respect the person. Moody might simply have agreed to it because Dumbledore asked him.

Comment: I don't think this is true. This is because of the wording that is used. "Special favor" implies that Moody owed Dumbledore something. Also, looking at Moody's personality, it seems that he is a man of honor (when he says to never attack someone from behind) but also doesn't go out of his way to perform random acts of kindness.

Comment: @InventPalooza It’s not a random act of kindness. I don’t think he would do it for many other people. But Dumbledore is his friend, they have worked together against Voldemort and the Death Eaters for many years, and he presumably highly respects him.

Comment: I agree that it's not a random act of kindness. I further agree that he regards Dumbledore with the highest respect. That still does not mean that he would go out of his way to give _anybody_ a favor. As mentioned throughout the book, Alastor Moody does not trust... well, anyone.

Comment: @InventPalooza So which aspect of my answer are you disagreeing with?

Comment: That Moody would do Dumbledore a favor without first owing him.

Comment: @InventPalooza Ah, you’re use of the word “anybody” confused me.

Comment: Right. I meant that Moody would not do **a single person / anybody** a random favor.

Comment: The only issue I have with this answer is; unless the doppelganger replaced Moody during the school year instead of before it, the quoted statement was made by the doppelganger.  Would he have known Moody's actual reason?

Comment: To show that Barty Crouch Jr knew the actual reason, you could add this quote from the end of the book from Crouch: "I kept him alive, under the Imperius Curse. I wanted to be able to
question him. To find out about his past, learn his habits, so that I could fool even
Dumbledore."

Comment: @InventPalooza People don't always do a favour in return for a previous favour. Sometimes they do a favour in order to call back a return favour at a later date.

Comment: @InventPalooza - *""Special favor" implies that Moody owed Dumbledore something."* No, it doesn't. Not in colloquial English (American or British). All it means is he's doing a favor for Dumbledore. The "special" modifier just means it's not a favor he'd do for just anyone, but it doesn't mean he *owes* Dumbledore. Just that he respects him, likes him, or whatever, and is willing to do him a favor he may not be willing to do for someone else.

Comment: *("American or British" - Hangs head at the narrowness of that statement. There are SO many other dialects of English...)*

Comment: @TJCrowder: And, really, only the British dialect matters.  It's what Rowling would use, and it's what her **British** characters in **Britain** would be using.

Comment: @InventPalooza Likewise, Moody seems like the sort that would not *owe* someone a random favor - he is proudly self-sufficient.

Comment: @JRE - Fair point. :-)

Comment: @InventPalooza If "a favor" always means you are paying back a favor, how could the first favor ever be given?

Comment: @AzorAhai It doesn't necessarily mean that... Just, in the case of Mad-Eye Moody, that is is what is most likely based on what is known of him throughout the book...

Comment: @InventPalooza In the case of Mad-Eye Moody, he seems exactly like the kind of person who would want to be owed a favor from one of the most powerful wizards alive.

Answer (score 17):

I have a translation of the 4th book by [A-ba-ba-ha-la-ma-ha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-ba-ba-ha-la-ma-ha), a highly respected publishing house in Ukraine.

> — То це ти син Артура Візлі? — спитав Муді. — Твій батько пару днів тому витяг мене з великої халепи… Так, я пробуду тут тільки рік. **І то лише заради Дамблдора...** один рік, а потім знову на пенсію.
>
> <sup>*Ukrainian*</sup>

*"Special favor to Dumbledore...."* was translated into *"І то лише заради Дамблдорa..."* which in Ukrainian unambiguously means *"only for Dumbledore's sake"*.

**Though, it really doesn't matter.** Don't forget that it was said by Bartemius Crouch Junior who was disguised as Moody. I don't know the real reason* why Moody was invited to Hogwarts as a teacher** and I am afraid the author didn't mention it anywhere.

Nevertheless, *"Special favor to Dumbledore...."* is a clever reply. It lulls the pupils into thinking that Dumbledore and Moody are good old friends, and consequently raises fewer questions about Moody's past and why he is a teacher.

---

<sub>* The real reason why Dumbledore invited Moody to the school​ is the Triwizard Tournament.

** The position is vacant. I guess having an auror as a teacher is less suspicious than hiring an auror for security purposes.</sub>

Comment: Would this "only for Dumbledore's sake" also cover if Dumbledore says "Moody, help me, please, you are my only hope", or does it imply some obligation like repayment for something that Dumbledore did for Moody?

Comment: @RalfFriedl *for sb’s sake* means *in order to help sb*, it doesn’t imply “obligation” or “sb’s only hope”

Comment: I wouldn't take a translation as being a better source than the original in determining intent - you're highly reliant on the interpreter and their personal interpretation of the line.

Comment: @Baldrickk I am not saying it’s better than the original. It was supposed to back up the post by Alex where the original quote had already been mentioned.

Comment: Come to think of it, a paranoid auditor is the most likely candidate for turning back a curse on a position.

Comment: This is an interesting take but the authorised German translation (from a highly respected publishing house, and a professional translator) is notoriously riddled with errors (missing half a chapter in the first edition of book 4!) and, if I remember correctly, the French translation likewise has issues. This emphasises what others have said: leeway in translations is in no way authoritative.

Comment: This is cool, but I am not sure how a Ukrainian translation could shed light on this. Most people here can easily read  and verify the quote in its original language.